# Importing from nameclashing packages which structure differs?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a package `foo` laid out like so:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── bar.py
    └── __init__.py
```

However, I have another package named `foo` in my `$PYTHONPATH`, laid out like so:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── qux.py
    └── __init__.py
```

All I really care about is importing `bar` from the former, and `qux` from the latter.

Is there a reasonably clean way to do that without resolving the conflict?  Specifically, taking advantage of the fact that the pacakges have a different structure despite sharing the same name?  (Specifically, the first contains a nested `bar`, the second a nested `qux`).

For example, if there was a way to `import foo` and get *all* the matching `foo` packages in a list, rather than just the first one in the `$PYTHONPATH`, I could iterate over them and test for `hasattr(package, 'bar')`.

It's legitimate to answer that this can't work, and there's no way to handle such a nameclash - i.e. more than one package in the `$PYTHONPATH` having the exact same name.

Comment: Where are you trying to get bar from? where is your script located? you cannot install two packages with the same name like this, maybe relative imports?

Comment: Can you make a symlink to whichever one is failing and import from that instead?

Comment: @Reznik: these are two external packages that share the same name. They are being imported from a script I'm working on.

Comment: @BenQuigley a solution like ad-hoc renaming or deep-linking one of the packages using a symlink can possibly working. I was hoping to find a solution to deal with this in Python.